# ScriptEngineManager eval(..) returns abridged value while summing up

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm trying to use ScriptEngineManager for summing two values and I getting not what I need.

I need to sum up System.currentTimeMillis() and some number of long type.

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
mathEvaluationEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String.valueOf(mathEvaluationEngine.eval(System.currentTimeMillis()+"+"+200000L));
```

For example if i'm trying to evaluate "1571316916817+200000L", I expect to get something like "1571317116817", but instead of that I received "1.571317116817E12". This problem only with the big numbers, smaller number are working perfectly. I dont want to receive the exponent value

Answer (score 0):

I'm just creating a new BigDecimal object from the eval result, it works just fine.